# VBA - Combine Multiple files into single worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Want to create a VBA script to combine multiple files in a folder, into a singular file 1 worksheet. All the files will have the same headers, so headers should only be imported from the first file.

Things to note:

- Headers will always be on first row (should only be imported from first file)
- Each file contains 1 worksheet
- Every file could have a variable number of rows after the header row
- End result must be all files combined into a single worksheet file with 1 header row.

Heres what I have so far:

```
Sub combineFiles()

'takes contents of files and puts into individual sheets
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'FolderPath = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\Test\"
FolderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
 For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
 Next Sheet
 Workbooks(Filename).Close
 Filename = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' combine sheets created by above script
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count ' from sheet 2 to last sheet
Sheets(J).Activate ' make the sheet active
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select ' select all cells in this sheets
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next

End Sub
```

This allowed me to get all files into 1. However, it seems to do it a random number of times, so if I have 2 files its combining them into the current file (as seperate sheets) 2/3/4 times each.
Second section of code doesnt run at all, which was meant to combine the different sheets together.

If someone can help find a more elegant (and working) way to combine these files it will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you have Excel 2010+ you can use [PowerQuery](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-files-in-a-folder-with-combine-binaries-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4)

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Thanks for that, I managed to get that working for my self on Office 365. However, the users in question who will be following these processes are on Office 2013, and after trying to install the Power Query on their PC, nothing happened. There is no Power Query tab as there should be on the older versions, no com add-in available and no errors occurred during install. So I may not be able to go down this route if we cannot get this working.

Comment: You stated that `Each file contains 1 worksheet`; if true, then you don't need to loop through each sheet.

Comment: Hi @GMalc, I know. The code I have i've put together and tweaked (ver slightly) from another stack overflow answer. The end result is not what I'm after though, becasue whether I loop through the sheets or not, I shouldnt be getting 2+ of every workbook.

Comment: Yes you will, because you use `ActiveWorkbook.FolderPath` and then loop through each workbook in the Folder, you will also duplicate all the worksheets you have added to the current workbook.

Comment: @GMalc The file im using is an xlsx file, does ```Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls")``` not explicitly search for only xls files?